# Nestjsx crud-request how to join for filter but exclude on response

Tags: crud, nestjs, typeorm

Im' using join because I'm filtering by a subproperty on an array field and in accordance to the documentation (Notice: Using nested filter shall join relation first.) you first have to join this field, but I don't want this array on the response, I just want the object.

this is my GET

`{{api}}/profile-doctor?join=patients&join=user&filter=patients.id||$eq||1&fields=id,title,consultation_address,consultation_phone,professional_id,rfc,photo,user`

I'm using fields for exclude patients but not works.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "",
        "consultation_address": "",
        "consultation_phone": "",
        "professional_id": "",
        "rfc": "",
        "photo": "",
        "patients": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "date_of_birthday": "",
                "phone_number": "",
                "phone_emergency": null,
                "address": "",
                "social_security_number": "",
                "genre": "",
                "height": "",
                "weight": ""
            }
        ],
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "",
            "lastname": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "",
        "consultation_address": "",
        "consultation_phone": "",
        "professional_id": "",
        "rfc": "",
        "photo": "",
        "patients": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "date_of_birthday": "",
                "phone_number": "",
                "phone_emergency": null,
                "address": "",
                "social_security_number": "",
                "genre": "",
                "height": "",
                "weight": ""
            }
        ],
        "user": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "",
            "lastname": ""
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Seem's that one solution is use [response dto](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#serialize)